# Bitmasking conversion of CPU ids with Go

Tags: string, go, binary, binary-operators

I have a mask that contains a binary counting of cpu_ids (`0xA00000800000` for 3 CPUs) which I want to convert into a `string` of comma separated cpu_ids: `"0,2,24"`.

I did the following Go implementation (I am a Go starter). Is it the best way to do it? Especially the handling of byte buffers seems to be inefficient!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main(){
    cpuMap     := "0xA00000800000"
    cpuIds     = getCpuIds(cpuMap)
    fmt.Println(cpuIds)
}

func getCpuIds(cpuMap string) string {
    // getting the cpu ids
    cpu_ids_i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(cpuMap, 0, 64) // int from string
    cpu_ids_b := strconv.FormatInt(cpu_ids_i, 2)    // binary as string

    var buff bytes.Buffer
    for i, runeValue := range cpu_ids_b {
        // take care! go returns code points and not the string    
        if runeValue == '1' {
            //fmt.Println(bitString, i)
            buff.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d", i))
        }
        if (i+1 < len(cpu_ids_b)) && (runeValue == '1') {
            //fmt.Println(bitString)
            buff.WriteString(string(","))
        }

    }
    cpuIds := buff.String()
    // remove last comma
    cpuIds = cpuIds[:len(cpuIds)-1]
    //fmt.Println(cpuIds)
    return cpuIds
}
```

Returns:

> "0,2,24"

Comment: Can you add the imports to the sample? It helps a lot when trying to use `go doc` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is essentially outputting the indices of the `"1"`'s in the binary representation from left-to-right, and starting index counting from the left (unusal).

You can achieve the same using bitmasks and bitwise operators, without converting it to a binary string. And I would return a slice of indices instead of its formatted string, easier to work with.

To test if the lowest (rightmost) bit is `1`, you can do it like `x&0x01 == 1`, and to shift a whole number bitwise to the right: `x >>= 1`. After a shift, the rightmost bit "disappears", and the previously 2nd bit becomes the 1st, so you can test again with the same logic. You may loop until the number is greater than 0 (which means it sill has 1-bits).

See this question for more examples of bitwise operations: [Difference between some operators "|", "^", "&", "&^". Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432398/difference-between-some-operators-golang/28433370#28433370)

Of course if we test the rightmost bit and shift right, we get the bits (indices) in *reverse* order (compared to what you want), and the indices are counted from right, so we have to correct this before returning the result.

So the solution looks like this:

```
func getCpuIds(cpuMap string) (r []int) {
    ci, err := strconv.ParseInt(cpuMap, 0, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    count := 0
    for ; ci > 0; count, ci = count+1, ci>>1 {
        if ci&0x01 == 1 {
            r = append(r, count)
        }
    }

    // Indices are from the right, correct it:
    for i, v := range r {
        r[i] = count - v - 1
    }
    // Result is in reverse order:
    for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
    }

    return
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q44cd2HxXu)):

```
[0 2 24]
```

If for some reason you need the result as a comma separated `string`, this is how you can obtain that:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
for i, v := range cpuIds {
    if i > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(",")
    }
    buf.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(v))
}
cpuIdsStr := buf.String()
fmt.Println(cpuIdsStr)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CVuj51G5BH)):

```
0,2,24
```