# Can I convert a bitencoded integer to array of bit positions?

Tags: go

I have a bit-wise coded value `0b00100110` and I want to extract an array of int with bit-positions like `[2,3,6]`.

I am very new to golang, so coming from C I would do this algorithmically. But I would like it to do the go-way

Comment: Why is algorithmically not the "go-way"? Just fill your slice with every 1 you find.

Comment: The algorithm to output indicies of the 1 bits can be found in this related question: [Bitmasking conversion of CPU ids with Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235464/bitmasking-conversion-of-cpu-ids-with-go/40235914#40235914)