# How to use bit instead of bool in golang structure?

Tags: go, struct, bit, memory-footprint

```
type EventPrefs struct {
    Call          bool
    Presence      bool 
    Endpoint      bool
    VoiceMail     bool
    CallRecording bool
}
```

Currently, the size of that struct type is 5 bytes but I would like to use bits. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You cannot, there are no bitfields in Go. You can do `type event uint8` and do the bitfiddling yourself.

Comment: Have you gathered empirical evidence that the memory footprint of your struct type actually is a problem? How about making its fields unexported now so you can be free to change its implementation later?

Comment: Bits are not individually addressable at the hardware level, which is why you have to use bitmasking like in any other language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no "bit" type in Go, so if you want to pack multiple `bool`  information into bits, you have to implement it yourself. Declare a field of type `uint8` (or `uint16` or any other integer type), and provide methods that get / set specific bits of the field.

General bit setting / clearing is as simple as this:

```
var masks = []uint8{0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10}

func set(field, data uint8, b bool) uint8 {
    if b {
        return data | masks[field] // Set bit
    }
    return data ^ masks[field] // Clear bit
}

func get(field, data uint8) bool {
    return data&masks[field] != 0
}
```

Packing your 5 bool fields into an `uint8` value:

```
type EventPrefs struct {
    data uint8
}

func (e *EventPrefs) SetCall(b bool) { e.data = set(0, e.data, b) }
func (e *EventPrefs) Call() bool     { return get(0, e.data) }

func (e *EventPrefs) SetPresence(b bool) { e.data = set(1, e.data, b) }
func (e *EventPrefs) Presence() bool     { return get(1, e.data) }

func (e *EventPrefs) SetEndpoint(b bool) { e.data = set(2, e.data, b) }
func (e *EventPrefs) Endpoint() bool     { return get(2, e.data) }

func (e *EventPrefs) SetVoiceMail(b bool) { e.data = set(3, e.data, b) }
func (e *EventPrefs) VoiceMail() bool     { return get(3, e.data) }

func (e *EventPrefs) SetCallRecording(b bool) { e.data = set(4, e.data, b) }
func (e *EventPrefs) CallRecording() bool     { return get(4, e.data) }
```

Testing it:

```
ep := &EventPrefs{}

fmt.Println("Calls:", ep.Call(), ep.data)
ep.SetCall(true)
fmt.Println("Calls:", ep.Call(), ep.data)

fmt.Println("Presence:", ep.Presence(), ep.data)
ep.SetPresence(true)
fmt.Println("Presence:", ep.Presence(), ep.data)
ep.SetPresence(false)
fmt.Println("Presence:", ep.Presence(), ep.data)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JQ7jkyhb7ZZ)):

```
Calls: false 0
Calls: true 1
Presence: false 1
Presence: true 3
Presence: false 1
```

Is saving 4 bytes worth the hassle? Rarely.

**Note:** the above solution can have many variations. For example the masks can be "computed" using bitshifts, the `set()` and `get()` functions could be methods of `EventPrefs` and so the `data` parameter would not be needed (and `set()` could directly set the `EventPrefs.data` field so no return value would be needed either). If `set()` remains a function, the `data` param could be a pointer so `set()` could change the pointed value without returning the new `data` etc. The `data` field may have its own declared type e.g. `bitpack` with `get()` and `set()` methods attached to it.

See related: [Difference between some operators "|", "^", "&", "&^". Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432398/difference-between-some-operators-golang/28433370#28433370)

Comment: thanks... @icza
will try this solution and hoping this will fulfil my requirements.